# What does 'ml' stand for in 'netbeans-7.0-ml-windows.exe'?

Tags: netbeans, version, netbeans-7

I have just downloaded Netbeans 7 and wondered what 'ml' stands for in 'netbeans-7.0-ml-windows.exe'?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain, but my guess would be "multi-lingual" or "multi-language", since NetBeans understands both Java and C++.

Comment: I used to think it was for milestone releases, but just checked, even dev releases have 'ml' in their name. Even downloading just C++ or just java SE shows 'ml'.

Comment: But if I select C++ only version of Netbeans, file is named 'netbeans-7.0-ml-cpp-windows.exe' It might not 'multi-lingual' or 'multi-languages'

Comment: Interesting, I would have guessed "multi-language" was referring to spoken, not programming languages...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "maintenance level"?

herp